# Why doesn't my ruby method call work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I use f.select onchange does not work for me, here is the code

```
<%= f.select :media, Model::MEDIA_TYPES, :include_blank => true, {}, { :onchange => "function(this);"} %>
```

A lot of functionality get messed up if I use this:

```
<%= select_tag "media_type", options_for_select(Model::MEDIA_TYPES),:include_blank => true, :onchange => "function(this);" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it should be:

```
<%= f.select :media, Model::MEDIA_TYPES, {:include_blank => true}, {:onchange => "..."} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra empty hash between your `option` and `html_options` parameters. Try:

```
<%= f.select :media, Model::MEDIA_TYPES, {:include_blank => true}, { :onchange => "function(this);"} %>
```